# Android 5.0 is unable to record 96000Hz audio?

Tags: java, android, audio, audiorecord, android-audiorecord

As the update of Android 5.0L mentioned (http://geeknizer.com/audio-improvements-in-android-5-0-l-audiophile/), Android starts to support 96000Hz sampling rate. However when I try to do this on my Galaxy S6:

```
void checkAvailableSampleRate(){
    for (int rate : new int[] {44100, 48000, 96000}) {  // add the rates you wish to check against
        int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        if (bufferSize > 0) {
            // buffer size is valid, Sample rate supported
            Log.d(C.LOG_TAG,"Sample rate "+rate+" is supportted");
            // just used for debugging
            AudioRecord temp = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, rate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);
            Log.d(C.LOG_TAG,"make audioRecord successfully ");
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to make 96000Hz work....

Here is the output I got:

```
Sample rate 44100 is supportted
Make audioRecord successfully
Sample rate 48000 is supportted
Make audioRecord successfully
Sample rate 96000 is supportted
```

My app crashes here so it means I can get the minBuffer when sample rate is set to 96000Hz but unable to create a AudioRecord instance.

and here is the error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 96000Hz is not a supported sample
>   rate.

It is weird to me that AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize() works fine with 96000Hz but app crashes when I try to create a 96000Hz AudioRecord.

Has anyone has tried to record 96000Hz audio in Android?

－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－

Here is the update of my gradle setting:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "edu.umich.cse.echotag"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ndk {
            moduleName "detection"
        }
    } ....
```

Comment: Have you compiled your code for the latest version of the API?

Comment: Hi Shotgun Ninja, I use the sdk version = 21. I also update my gradle setting in my question.

Answer (score 0):

The OS may support 96k but the hardware also needs to support 96k to make that work.

`getMinBufferSize` may not be a robust way to check the hardware supported sample rates.
see here [How can I find out what Sampling rates are supported on my tablet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549709/how-can-i-find-out-what-sampling-rates-are-supported-on-my-tablet)

`AudioManager` can query native parameters for the device. If you want to check for whether 96k is supported, this might be useful.

```
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: "+am.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_FRAMES_PER_BUFFER));
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: "+am.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE));
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: "+am.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_SUPPORT_MIC_NEAR_ULTRASOUND));
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: "+am.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_SUPPORT_SPEAKER_NEAR_ULTRASOUND));
```

more reading http://geeknizer.com/audio-improvements-in-android-5-0-l-audiophile/

Hope it can help you.