# Sound Plays from Smarthpone Speakers instead Android Auto Speakers

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am new to Android Auto and still trying to figure it out. 
I have successfully played music from my own programmed app but the music is coming out from my smartphone speakers instead of car speakers. Other (sample) apps do it the right way.

Which part of of the Media System is responsible to handle this behaviour? Android documentation says the sound is sent to the car speakers.

```
   @Override
    public void onPlayFromMediaId(String mediaId, Bundle extras) {

        this.mPlayingQueue.add(item);
        session.setActive(true);
        session.setQueue(mPlayingQueue);
        session.setQueueTitle("My Queue");
        session.setPlaybackState(buildState(PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY));
        session.setMetadata(createRammsteinMetaData());

        this.mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.rammstein_sonne);
        this.mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);


        if (tryToGetAudioFocus()) {
            this.mediaPlayer.start();
            Log.d("AUDIOTAG", "Playing");
        } else {
            Log.d("AUDIOTAG", "Playing not possible, no focus");
        }
    }

    private boolean tryToGetAudioFocus() {
        int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
        return result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED;
    }
```

Thanks in advance. Orrimp

Comment: Try `this.mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);`

Comment: Interessting Idea but it only works with STREAM_MUSIC and without any AudioStreamType. STREAM_VOICE_CALL and others not even playing. (Volume is set to 1.0f)

Comment: I tried playing audio with OpenSL two years ago when I used to work with JNI. Anyway, I faced similar problem there. The audio was playing in speaker instead of ear speaker. I solved the problem here. You can have a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576739/how-to-configure-opensl-to-work-with-ear-speaker-other-than-main-speaker-or-head/

Comment: But didn't face any problem with MediaPlayer. It worked just fine with ear speakers.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a pretty big bug there! Local music from resources does not play properly using MediaPlayer.create(...);

Thx **Reaz Murshed** I just tried to use the STREAM_MUSIC as a real stream with Internet Music and it works. 
Translate to use setDataSource with Resource URI!
Use the following snippet:

```
    @Override
    public void onPlayFromMediaId(String mediaId, Bundle extras) {

        /* Set session stuff like queue, metadata and so on*/

        Uri myUri = resourceToUri(getBaseContext(), R.raw.rammstein_sonne);
        try {
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getBaseContext(), myUri);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    if (tryToGetAudioFocus()) {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        Log.d("AUDIOTAG", "Playing");
                    } else {
                        Log.d("AUDIOTAG", "Playing not possible, no focus");
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("AUTO", "EERORROR");
        }
    }

    public Uri resourceToUri(Context context, int resID) {
        return Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" +
                context.getResources().getResourcePackageName(resID) + '/' +
                context.getResources().getResourceTypeName(resID) + '/' +
                context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(resID));
    }
```