# Android OpenSL ES, how to choose speaker

Tags: android, opensl

Does anyone know how to play the sound through the speaker that we normally use during the phone conversation (not the loud speaker, but the ear speaker)? I have developed the app similar to Skype and my only problem is that when the sound is played through the loud speakers, mic picks it up and there is a lot of nose generated...
In my code this is the line that I figured controls which speaker is used...

```
SLDataFormat_PCM format_pcm = {SL_DATAFORMAT_PCM, 1, SL_SAMPLINGRATE_8,
                                   SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16, SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16,
                                   SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_CENTER, SL_BYTEORDER_LITTLEENDIAN};
```

There are other options instead of SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_CENTER namely:

```
#define SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_LEFT           ((SLuint32) 0x00000001)
#define SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_RIGHT          ((SLuint32) 0x00000002)
#define SL_SPEAKER_LOW_FREQUENCY        ((SLuint32) 0x00000008)
#define SL_SPEAKER_BACK_LEFT            ((SLuint32) 0x00000010)
#define SL_SPEAKER_BACK_RIGHT           ((SLuint32) 0x00000020)
#define SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_LEFT_OF_CENTER ((SLuint32) 0x00000040)
#define SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_RIGHT_OF_CENTER    ((SLuint32) 0x00000080)
#define SL_SPEAKER_BACK_CENTER          ((SLuint32) 0x00000100)
#define SL_SPEAKER_SIDE_LEFT            ((SLuint32) 0x00000200)
#define SL_SPEAKER_SIDE_RIGHT           ((SLuint32) 0x00000400)
#define SL_SPEAKER_TOP_CENTER           ((SLuint32) 0x00000800)
#define SL_SPEAKER_TOP_FRONT_LEFT       ((SLuint32) 0x00001000)
#define SL_SPEAKER_TOP_FRONT_CENTER     ((SLuint32) 0x00002000)
#define SL_SPEAKER_TOP_FRONT_RIGHT      ((SLuint32) 0x00004000)
#define SL_SPEAKER_TOP_BACK_LEFT            ((SLuint32) 0x00008000)
#define SL_SPEAKER_TOP_BACK_CENTER      ((SLuint32) 0x00010000)
#define SL_SPEAKER_TOP_BACK_RIGHT       ((SLuint32) 0x00020000)
```

I have tried all of them and none work.
Thanks Alex.

Comment: Found solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576739/how-to-configure-opensl-to-work-with-ear-speaker-other-than-main-speaker-or-head

Comment: Found solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576739/how-to-configure-opensl-to-work-with-ear-speaker-other-than-main-speaker-or-head