# PocketSphinx Recording IllegalStateException Error for AudioRecord object

Tags: android, cmusphinx, android-audiorecord

On some devices (none of the actual test devices), I get a force close when I start PocketSphinx recognition, the crash report is as follows (note it was previously obfuscated):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.
at android.media.AudioRecord.startRecording(AudioRecord.java:515)
at edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.SpeechRecognizer.setSearch(Unknown Source)
at edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.SpeechRecognizer$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Based on the crash reports, it seems that it is not specific to a certain device...

[image]

Comment: The error says that audiorecord can not be initialized. Most like it can't record at 16khz and you need to use 8khz model (hub4wsj_sc_8k) instead of en_us_semi. You also need to change samplerate in config.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Is there any advantage to using the 16khz mmodel? Would it be worth it to include both and allow users to choose between them?

Comment: No, there is no great advantage in that, 8khz model is also ok for keyword activation. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043387/android-audiorecord-supported-sampling-rates

Comment: I changed to the 8khz model, but was still having trouble and I realized that PocketSphinx wasn't calling release on its AudioRecord object so I fixed this, but I still get this issue sporadically... I'm going to try to add a wait for initialization check to see if this fixes it...