# Nexus 9 primary sample rate

Tags: android, android-ndk, opensl

I have an app that uses OpenSL ES. When I try to use it on a Nexus9 6.0.1, I hear a noise like I have the wrong sampling rate. On other devices all is OK.

My `SLDataFormat_PCM` structure:

```
SLDataFormat_PCM format_pcm = {
            SL_DATAFORMAT_PCM,
            aChannels,
            48000 * 1000,
            SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16,
            SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16,
            aChannels == 2 ? SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_LEFT | SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_RIGHT
                           : SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_CENTER,
            SL_BYTEORDER_LITTLEENDIAN
    };
```

When I change the sample rate (+/- 1Hz) in this structure, the output sounds OK, but I receive an `AudioTrack` debug message:

`W/AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client; transfer 1, track 47999 Hz, output 48000 Hz`

**Why do I have a problem in FAST mode, if the Nexus9 has 48000Hz?**

I checked it using this method:

```
jclass clazz = env.getEnv()->FindClass("android/media/AudioSystem");
jmethodID mid = env.getEnv()->GetStaticMethodID(clazz, "getPrimaryOutputSamplingRate", "()I");
int nSampleRate = env.getEnv()->CallStaticIntMethod(clazz, mid);
LOGDEBUG << "Sample Rate: " << nSampleRate;
```

`[ DBG:c894860f] 11:16:14.902: Sample Rate: 48000`

**Is there a better method to get device's sample rate?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with mutex in callback function.

UPD:
[OpenSLES Readme](https://github.com/nettoyeurny/opensl_stream/blob/master/README.md)

> Known issues
>
> At 48000Hz, Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 10 produce glitchy output. At
>   44100Hz, Galaxy Nexus tends to glitch when switching activities or
>   bringing up large dialogs. Touch sounds occasionally cause OpenSL to
>   glitch. It's probably a good idea to disable touch sounds in audio
>   apps. These problems are not specific to opensl_stream and have been
>   reproduced in other settings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there's a method to find the preferred sample rate for a device though it'll work for API level > 16. [You can have a look at my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22317382/3145960).

And about your `SLDataFormat_PCM` structure. You've initialized with sample rate 48k*1k! If you want to sample your PCM data in 48k, try using the code below.

```
// configure audio source
SLDataFormat_PCM format_pcm = {
        SL_DATAFORMAT_PCM,
        aChannels,
        SL_SAMPLINGRATE_48,
        SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16,
        SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16,
        aChannels == 2 ? SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_LEFT | SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_RIGHT
                       : SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_CENTER,
        SL_BYTEORDER_LITTLEENDIAN
};
```

I didn't work with Nexus 9 before, so I don't know if it supports 48k sampling rate. But, anyway, you can check if it supports.